# How come my scrolling after Keyboard is shown is not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

So I've implemented the Apple's Recommended [way](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) of managing the keyboard.

But my view still does not scroll up or down if the activeTextfield is behind the keyboard. I get the feeling that I am missing something fundamental.

That's why I've decided to post all my code below. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code in my .m file:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification     object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your app might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
}
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

I have scroll view proper declared in the .h file like as following:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

*note that my scroll view in inside a view(this view property is not declared in .h) in the view controller.

and I've implemented the following:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
activeField = nil;
}
```

The code below use to work for resigning the keyboard before I embedded all my textfields into a scroll view. However, it is now not functioning.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 NSLog(@"TOUCH TOUCH");
if ([_cardnumbertext isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _cardnumbertext) {
    [_cardnumbertext resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"TOUCH TOUCH0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the contentSize property on your scroll view? Please try to put this line before calling scrollToRectVisible:animate:.

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + kbSize.height)];
```

Comment: I added this code right before [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES]; nothing appeared to have changed